# How do I pass parameters to a method both as normal and like a property?

Tags: vb.net, visual-studio-2013, declaration, realbasic, xojo

In RealBasic (now Xojo), which I'm leaving to the past, I used to be able to declare a method like this:

```
Sub MyCoolSub(param1 as string, Assigns parameter2 as integer)
Do
'Waste CPU time scrying the universe.
Loop
End Sub
```

And then call it in this way:

```
MyCoolSub("Answer")=42
```

Now I'd want to replicate this behaviour in VB.Net.

The closest thing I stumbled upon is the Property's clauses,  <s>but VS does not let me add parameters to it</s> that would however require some overhead which decreases the convenience of this type of declaration.

Do you have any better suggestion?

*PS. As a side question I would be pretty happy to know that there is a way to comment with "//" in VB.Net, as I'm not that comfortable with the apostrophe character. Is there any thing as a VS comment characters list? Maybe an extension could do it...*

Comment: I don't know RealBasic or Xojo. Can you explain in words what it is that `MyCoolSub("Answer")=42` is supposed to do. To answer your second question, VB comments use a single apostrophe and not "//".

Comment: not often used, but `Rem` can be used to mark comments as well.  Once Upon a Time it was short for `Remark` or use `'//` if you are looking to make it look familiar

Comment: @Blackwood, the question is about how to get param1="Answer" and param2=42, while still calling the method as I showed. I consider this a really interesting feature of that language.

Comment: The only thing I can think of that does that is the Set clause of a Property. See the answer posted by Bjørn-Roger Kringsjå.

Comment: I've seen it, I will probably mark it as THE answer, if nothing else pops in the near future.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

When I look at the documentation for the [Xojo Assigns keyword](http://docs.xojo.com/index.php/Assigns) the closest thing I can think of is to create a write-only property like this:

```
Public WriteOnly Property theVolume(a As Integer, b As Integer) As Integer
    Set(c As Integer)
        Debug.WriteLine("a={0}, b={1}, c={2}", a, b, c)
    End Set
End Property
```

```
theVolume(1, 2) = 3
```

> a=1, b=2, c=3

Comment: I didn't know that adding parameters to properties were possible. So far this is the best answer, despite the loss of convenience...

Comment: @beppe9000 I'm pretty sure this is as close as it ever gets ;)

Answer (score 2):

Regarding your "P.S." note:

to ease your switching to VB.NET you can use the following [AutoHotKey](http://ahkscript.org) command:

```
:O://::'
```

This will do the appropriate substitution for you during typing.
You can limit it only to your IDE window using `#IfWinActive` directive.

Anyway, Roslyn VB.Net compiler is now [open source](https://github.com/dotnet/roslyn/tree/master/src/Compilers/VisualBasic) so you can download and play...

Comment: I'm not on *that* level... however thanks for the AutoHotKey suggestion ;)